# Issues reading data using read.csv and read.table in R

Tags: mysql, r, csv

I have a data which is exported from mysql using the following command,

```
SELECT 
    id_code,info_text INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/company-desc.csv' 
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' 
    OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM 
    dx_company WHERE LENGTH(id_code) = 8 AND 
    id_code REGEXP '^[0-9]+$';
```

But when I try to load the csv using the following commands in R,

```
 dt.companydesc <- read.csv("company-desc.csv",sep=';',fill=T, encoding = "UTF-8",quote="\n",header=FALSE)
```

or

```
dt.companydesc <- read.csv("company-desc.csv",sep=';',fill=T, encoding = "UTF-8",quote="\"",header=FALSE)
```

it yeilds results like:

```
Id code  description
2345     This is the description \n344555 \n737384 \n388383 \n000083
```

some id's are mixed with description.
it is basically having problem with quotes and \n while reading. If I try to give both I disturbs the whole table.
I also tried gsub and readLines.
Any help.

Snapshot of:(CSV File)

```
  "1000004";"general"
  "1000000";"licensed version, and products"
  "1000007";""
  "1000003";""
  "1000002";""
  "1000006";""
  "1000002";"automobiles; well organised"
```

Desired output:

```
   Id_code  Description
  1000004  general
  1000000  licensed version, and products
  1000007  NA
  1000003  NA
  1000002  NA
  1000006  NA
  1000002  automobiles and industry; well organised
```

Comment: post an example along with expected output.

Comment: My guess is that your `quote` argument is incorrect, but I can't be sure without seeing a sample of the CSV file.

Comment: `quote="\n"` is kind of unseen. You are saying to MySQL that the separator is the comma and then you use the `;` when you call `read.csv`. Are you sure about that?

Comment: sorry I corrected the mysql statement, I actually tried giving different separators

Comment: I can read your snapshot with `read.csv2` easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way using `data.table::fread`, which is also faster:

```
require(data.table) # v1.9.6+
fread('  "1000004";"general"
  "1000000";"licensed version, and products"
  "1000007";""
  "1000003";""
  "1000002";""
  "1000006";""
  "1000002";"automobiles; well organised"', na.strings="", 
header=FALSE, col.names=c("Id_code", "Description"))

#    Id_code                    Description
# 1: 1000004                        general
# 2: 1000000 licensed version, and products
# 3: 1000007                             NA
# 4: 1000003                             NA
# 5: 1000002                             NA
# 6: 1000006                             NA
# 7: 1000002    automobiles; well organised
```

Comment: They should probably avoid the CSV step and query the database from R.